# I want to do filter by selecting multiple textbox using php or other languages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, filtering

I'm developing the final project which is a website for my college and I'm developing this using PHP. The project has 6 fields for filtering. So I want to use one or more than one field to filter the data. But there is show error if I keep blank one or more fields. So please help me out. I've 2 different codes. One work if I use any one field. but another code must use 6 fields otherwise show errors.

work only use any one field.

```
if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {
            if (!empty($_POST['thana'])) {
                $fthana = $_POST['thana'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM postad WHERE status='1' AND thana = '$fthana' ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
                $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['area'])) {
                $farea = $_POST['area'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM postad WHERE status='1' AND area = '$farea' ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
                $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['category'])) {
                $fcategory = $_POST['category'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM postad WHERE status='1' AND category = '$fcategory' ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
                $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['whom'])) {
                $fwhom = $_POST['whom'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM postad WHERE status='1' AND whom = '$fwhom' ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
                $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['available'])) {
                $favailable = $_POST['available'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM postad WHERE status='1' AND available = '$favailable' ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
                $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['rent'])) {
                $frent = $_POST['rent'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM postad WHERE status='1' AND rent <= '$frent' ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
                $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
```

2nd work if I used 6 fields. But show error If I keep blank any one or more than one field.

```
if ($fthana!="" && $farea!="" && $fcategory!="" && $fwhom!="" && $favailable!="" & $frent!="") {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM postad WHERE status='1' AND thana = '$fthana' AND area = '$farea' AND category = '$fcategory' AND whom = '$fwhom' AND available = '$favailable' AND rent = '$frent' ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
                $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
```

Comment: And we should guess the error text?

Comment: to be fair to @u_mulder it ought to be stated here that the above code is potentially vulnerable to sql injection and that a better approach ought to be sought

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version (without taking security issues into consideration) of your code can be someting like:

```
$where = [];
if ($fthana!="") {
    $where[] = "thana = '$fthana'";
} 

if ($farea!="") {
    $where[] = "area = '$farea'"
}

if ($fcategory!="") {
    $where[] = "category = '$fcategory'";
}
// more conditions here

$query = "SELECT * FROM postad WHERE status='1' AND " .  implode(' AND ', $where) . " ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: whilst being considerably more refined it does not address potential sql injection issues

Comment: everything is ok but if I use 1st field then other fields get an error : 
Notice: Undefined index: area in  
Notice: Undefined index: category in
Notice: Undefined index: whom in
Notice: Undefined index: available in
Notice: Undefined index: rent in

Comment: So think how to remove these messages. SO already has answers for such kind of problem